Is it possible to generate a .dSYM file for an iOS app using dotnet publish command?
We would prefer to use the dotnet publish command but we need the .dSYM file for reasons. We find that the time to generate the .ipa file is much quicker with dotnet publish, so that is the preferred method to get our app in the release pipeline. However, no .dsym file is generated during the dotnet publish.

This question is similar to: How to generate .dSYM file for .NET MAUI app. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here is how to publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS and include your Code Signing Key and Provisioning Profile to generate a .dSYM file:
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release -p:ArchiveOnBuild=true -p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 -p:CodesignKey="Apple Distribution: John Smith (AY2GDE9QM7)" -p:CodesignProvision="MyProvisioningProfile"

After publishing the iOS/MacCatalyst app using dotnet publish, you can find + retrieve the .dSYM file using the following steps:

Open Xcode
In Xcode, in the menu bar, navigate to Window -> Organizer

Alternatively, in Xcode, use the keyboard shortcut cmd + option + shift + o


In the Xcode Archives window, in the top left corner of the window, use the drop-down to select the app for which you want the .dsym file
In the Xcode Archives window, on the left-hand menu, select Archives
In the Xcode Archives window, locate the version of the published app
In the right-click menu, select Show in Finder
In Finder, locate the .xcarchive file, right-click -> Show Package Contents
In Finder, you'll now find the dSYMS folder where you .dSYM file is located



I do development in Visual Studio Code, the project is not configured with xcode. I've seen this answer in the other post before, but unfortunately this is using xcode.

You are using Xcode. Every .NET MAUI project requires Xcode to compile iOS + macOS apps. The MAUI tooling communicates with Xcode for you automatically under the hood. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms

Ok, turns out that the .dSYM archive file was being created all this time, but I was not seeing this because Visual Studio makes the file look like a folder, rather than a file. I misinterpreted this and thought it wasn't being created.

Try this
Use the dotnet publish command to build the app dotnet publish -c Release -t:iOS
Open the generated .ipa file in Xcode.
Select the "Products" tab and right-click on the app bundle.
Choose "Show in Finder."
Right-click on the app bundle in Finder and select "Show Package Contents."
Navigate to the "dSYMs" folder.
You'll find the .dSYM file for your app.
Let me know if it helps :)
